# React native, the useEffect on a object state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

Here is the code before the render

```
const HappyComponent = (props) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));    // the props are ok

    const [HHDays, setHHDays] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const hours = props.infos.happy ?
            {
                allWeek: { from: props.infos.ending, to: props.infos.strating, showPickerFrom: false, showPickerTo: false },
            }
            :
            {
                allWeek: { from: "", to: "", showPickerFrom: false, showPickerTo: false },
            }
        setHHDays(hours);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(HHDays));
    }, []);

    return (
```

So the `state` of `HHDays` stays `null` and the render shows an error on the frist `{HHDays.allWeek.from}`

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'HHDays.allWeek')

Comment: useEffect is called after the component was rendered. So when the code reaches that line the first time around, it tries to read `null.from`.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to move all that is inside the useEffect inside useState (the default value).

Comment: how can I make the useeffect proceed before the render so ? I thought it was doing like that

Comment: You can't, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` is called after the component was rendered. So when the code reaches that line the first time around, it tries to read `null.from`.

Maybe you'd want to move all that which is inside the `useEffect` inside `useState`, as the default value. You don't actually need a `useEffect` here.

```
const [HHDays, setHHDays] = useState(props.infos.happy ?
            {
                allWeek: { from: props.infos.ending, to: props.infos.strating, showPickerFrom: false, showPickerTo: false },
            }
            :
            {
                allWeek: { from: "", to: "", showPickerFrom: false, showPickerTo: false },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty object to useState instead of null

`const [HHDays, setHHDays] = useState({});`

Answer (score -4):

SetState is an asynchronous call, meaning, its unclear if the state is changed when the code reaches the log. If you need to make sure the state is set, you can use a timeout or a useeffect based on state changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).